# How to change LaTex paper left, right, top and botton margins?

Tags: margins

I just want to change the paper left, right, top and botton margins in ***LaTex*** because I think the default margins isn't enough.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout).

Comment: The [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package is just for that purpose.